# Connecting scatter points in matlab

Tags: matlab, line, scatter

I have a dataset with points (X,Y coordinates) that represent the shape of a glacier. However, when I plot them with

```
% Import glacier shape

Glaciershape = readtable('dem_glacierlocation.txt');

figure(1);
S = Glaciershape(:,1);
T = Glaciershape(:,2);
plot(S,T,'-')
```

[image]

It seems that an points connect when they don't need to (see attachment, at the left upper corner of the shape). Is there a way to fix this? You can download the dataset in the link below

Thanks!

[Download text file glacier](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/73521/dem_glacierlocation.txt)

Comment: `plot` connects sequential points, it has no concept of whether or not points "need" to be connected. You'll want to isolate the interior portions of the data and plot them separately.

Answer (score 0):

`plot` will assume every set of x,y coords is sequential in a series and plot them all without a care as to content.

If you could make some assumption about the distribution of points then you could use that to break on those that fail. For example, a point in the series is always less than 100 units from the previous point. Otherwise, this begins a new series list. Using that you could do a check on distance between subsequent points using `diff` as in:

```
% assume data stored in xcoord,ycoord
% check for distance greater than 100
idx = find(sqrt(diff(xcoords).^2 + diff(ycoords).^2) > 100 );
% in this particular data set there are 3 disjoint sections
% plot out each section - here each done explicitly for illustration
plot(xcoords(1:idx(1)),ycoords(1:idx(1)));
hold on;
plot(xcoords(idx(1)+1:idx(2)),ycoords(idx(1)+1):idx(2));
plot(xcoords(idx(2)+1:idx(3)),ycoords(idx(2)+1):idx(3));
plot(xcoords(idx(3)+1:end),ycoords(idx(2)+1):end);
```

edit: added other plot's after looking at data file provided

hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the shortest path connecting all dots in a loop, this is known as the traveling [salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), which is very difficult to solve.

If you are just looking for an easy way to visualize try:

```
plot(S,T,'.')
```

where you replace the '-' you had above with '.'.  This will plot the x,y coordinates unconnected and you can let the human brain do the connections, which it is good at.

Here is the image without connections.  It looks like at the top there are two areas which are holes, which is why connecting all the points might be problematic.

[image]